# make a picture box into an hotmail captcha

Tags: c#, captcha, picturebox, src

I'm trying to get pictureBox1 to be the same image as it appears on hotmail when you creating an account.

I got the following:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElementCollection he = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img"); string src;
        foreach (HtmlElement el in he)
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("src").Contains("client.hip.live.com/GetHIPData?hid="))
            {

                src = el.GetAttribute("src");
                pictureBox1.ImageLocation = src;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

but its not working, I'm getting the captcha URL but its not showing up on my program, I heard you need to take a screenshot of that and then paste it on the pictureBox1 but I never done anything similar.

Comment: What do you want to do? You only want to show the picture, or you also wish to validate the response of a user? If it's just to show the picture, download it using webclient / httpwebrequest and save it to a local file to show it

Comment: I just want to show the picture. you cannot download it using webclient as its dynamic image and not the same all the time

Comment: then setting the imagelocation will also not do it :) (as in the background, it does the loading with webclient)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot by using this code

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap([somewidth], [someheight], PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage( b))
{
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.CopyFromScreen(new Point([your calculated X coordinate], [calculated y coordinate]), new Point(0, 0), new Size(b.Width, b.Height));
}
```

Bitmap b, would then contain the part you wish to copy, however, you would need to do a little effort in calculating the position of the bitmap :)